# how do I change schema owner in ms sql server?

Tags: sql-server, kentico

I currently have a website hosted developed with kentico 7. I tried importing the exported website into my localhost and that failed. In my findings, i realised that each table in the online version has a bvs (the database user created) prefix. I have tried creating the same scenario on my localhost without any luck. Does anyone have an idea ?

Here is the error displayed at importation.

[image]

Comment: what the error you are getting? create bvs user and schema on the localhost and then import.

Comment: i did that already. I noticed I have the prefix dbo on all my tables in localhost and bvs on all tables in the online version. I have tried `EXEC sp_changedbowner 'bvs'` but it returned the error : `The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the database.`

Comment: "I tried importing the exported website into my localhost and that failed" what failure did you get?

Comment: See my update for the error page.

Answer (score 19):

You can change the schema owner using this command:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::bvs TO db_owner;
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this out:

```
USE MyDB
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::bvs TO dbo;
GO 
SP_DROPUSER 'bvs'
GO
SP_CHANGEDBOWNER 'bvs'
```

Comment: `The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped.` and `The proposed new database owner is already a user or aliased in the database.` respectively

Comment: I have. The result is what I posted in my comment.

Comment: @Rookie13 Could you also explain your answer? Such answers are always stronger.

Comment: Stronger? I am suggesting Peter to change the authorization for user 'bvs' to dbo. so he can have permissions to drop and change dbowner.

Comment: @Rookie13, thanks for your responses so far. currently I have my tables with the prefix `dbo` while I want it as `bvs` (I'm trying to be as simple as possible). I believe if I can achieve that, my issues will be resolved. Any idea?

Comment: Check out this article and see if it provides any information that might be useful: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2620/steps-to-drop-an-orphan-sql-server-user-when-it-owns-a-schema-or-role/

Comment: WARNING: This will drop all existing permissions on objects in the schema.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/247459/176679.